# Articles before possession clause (<somebody>'s <something>)

Tags: articles, possessives

To express meanings **“The car of Tom”** and **“One of the cars of Tom”**, which articles do I put before **“Tom’s car”**?

And in general, if an article appears before **<somebody>’s <something>**, which word does it belong to? Is it **<somebody>** or **<something>**?

Comment: In general, you *can't* put an article before a noun with a Saxon genitive, because syntactically both the genitive **'s** and the articles **a, the** are *determiners*, and usually you can only have *one* determiner for a noun.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used a noun in the examples. "Man's" would has been a better choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tom's car" means "the car of Tom", and "Tom's" is a definite determiner, which functions like "the".  If you want an indefinite, you have to use a different construction: "a car of Tom's".

An indefinite article can occur at the beginning of a possessive construction, e.g. "a man's car", but this is still a definite noun phrase, since it means "the car of a man" -- the indefinite "a" goes with "man", not "car", and "a man's" is a definite determiner.

In general, you can build a possessive definite determiner by adding "'s" to a noun phrase: "[the old man]'s car", "[a lady who I used to know]'s car".  However, so far as I know, you can't make a possessive determiner from a nominalized sentence by adding "'s", even though it is a noun phrase.

Comment: Thank you Greg, great answer, exactly what I needed to know